# How to set Number of Dynamic Tile in HCP portal service?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, sap-cloud-platform

I just want to use number from my server to change tile number, such as using URL `http://10.59.XXX.100:8080/Map/dynamicTileOnlyNo`

In [SCN blog](http://scn.sap.com/community/hana-cloud-portal/blog/2015/05/03/flphana-cloud-platform--building-managing-applications-for-fiori-launchpad-sites-part-2), they use `/sap/fiori/employees/destinations/northwind/V3/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Employees/$count` to set dynamic data

which stand for 
`/<fiori proxy>/<application id>/destinations/<destination name>/<path to OData service>/<OData collection>/<query string>`

But I tried http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Employees/$count , returned:

```
Failed to update data via service /sap/fiori/realtimealerthttp://10.59.172.100:8080/Map/dynamicTileOnlyNo: HTTP request failed - 404 Not Found -  sap.ushell.components.tiles.applauncherdynamic.DynamicTile
```

Why HCP add `/sap/fiori/realtimealert` in front? Should I set something in Destinations?

I tried add destinations in "Configure Portal Service ":

Name: northwind

URL: http://services.odata.org/

Still returned:

> GET
>   https://flpportal-iXXXXXXtrial.dispatcher.hanatrial.ondemand.com/sap/fiori/alert/destinations/northwind/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Employees/$count
>   404 (Not Found)

Must I use odata or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the SCN blog, you need to use relative paths in the URL in combination with odata.
It also seems like your destinations are not configured properly.
Please check HCP documentation on this.