# Failed to get metadata while adding dynamic tile to fiori launchpad

Tags: odata, sap-fiori

I want to register a new tile in my Fiori Launchpad that contains dynamic data.

I registered the destination in the SAP Cloud Platform cockpit:
[image: destination]

Added in the `neo-app.json` file:

```
"routes": [
    {
      "path": "/destinations/TripPinRESTierService",
      "target": {
        "type": "destination",
        "name": "TripPinRESTierService"
      },
      "description": "TripPinRESTierService description"
    }
]
```

And in the manifest as a datasource:

```
"dataSources": {
        "trippin": {
            "uri": "/destinations/TripPinRESTierService",
            "type": "OData",
            "settings": {
                "odataVersion": "2.0"
            }
        }
}
```

When I choose "Dynamic" in the Fiori Launchpad registration process for the tile type, it says me that it

> could not find the service URL.

I should enter it manually.

I added `/destinations/TripPinRESTierService` and got the error

> Failed to get the metadata of the service
> /destinations/TripPinRESTierService/': The resource
> you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is
> temporarily unavailable. Choose a static tile

So, what am I doing wrong? How can I get the metadata?

Comment: You added manually `destinations/TripPinRESTierService`?

Shouldn’t it be `/destinations/TripPinRESTierService`?   
With a forward slash at the beginning ?

In your manifest.json it says:
`"uri": "/destinations/TripPinRESTierService"`   
Is this the correct URI to your OData service?

Comment: I tried this, too. Unfortunately, it doesn't work either.

Comment: In your manifest.json it says: `"uri": "/destinations/TripPinRESTierService"` 
Is this the correct URI to your OData service?
Usually it is something like `“/sap/opu/odata/sap/TripPinRESTierService”`, but it might be different in your system.
What happens if you insert your system + your OData Service in the URL of the browser?
Do you get a valid response?

Comment: This URL should be correct. I get the data in my application. 
`http://services.odata.org/TripPinRESTierService` returns a valid response.
I noticed that I get a `404 not found` error when I want to use it for a new master detail kapsel application. But when I try the connection in the destination configurator, it can access the service.

Comment: What happens if you skip the “/destination” and just try “/TripPinRESTierService” as service URL?
Please also see [Dynamic Tile](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/01/25/dynamic-tile-in-sap-webide); [How to set Number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39619500/how-to-set-number-of-dynamic-tile-in-hcp-portal-service); [Customizing Fiori Application Launch Tiles](https://blogs.sap.com/2015/05/03/flphana-cloud-platform-building-managing-applications-for-fiori-launchpad-sites-part-2); [Create Dynamic App launcher Fiori Tile](https://blogs.sap.com/2015/03/06/create-dynamic-app-launcher-fiori-tile)

Comment: Thanks for your tips! I got right now to call the URL in the browser `(https://webide-[myId]trial.dispatcher.hanatrial.ondemand.com/destinations/TripPinRESTierService/TripPinRESTierService)`

I added `/TripPinRESTierService` to the URL in the destination configuration and also to the URL for the dynamic tile. Furthermore, I added the destination to my neo-app.json file.

But I still get an error (500) when I take the URL that works in the browser for my dynamic tile data...